# im thinking to buy a laptop which is unregistered. its a new laptop without registration of its ip address

Tags: anonymity

I'm thinking to buy a laptop,its directly imported from a ship or maybe stolen,i don't know ,but its ip address is not registered ..so if I will buy it then is it safe ? Can I be traced by the police when I'll use internet on my laptop ? Because that will be an unregistered laptop.

Comment: What do you mean by "IP address not registered"? There's no such a thing like _laptop registration_...

Comment: If you even consider that the laptop is stolen, just walk away!! Apart from the obvious moral issues, how can you even possibly trust the vendor? Hardware malware / backdoors are adequately documented from 'real' vendors, let alone some dodgy transaction.

Comment: @ThoriumBR the laptop seller is saying that the laptop is directly imported from the ship.means where they import from other countries. So that laptop didn't go to the maker company..i mean to say there will be some process that the imported goods comes by the ship and then it goes to the dealer or distributor ? Then it is available for the common people at stores ? Isn't it ? So it laptop will be purchased by me before going to the distributor ? That means it wont be legally a part of company.it will be misaing from their list.

Comment: @joe hey joe thanks for ur suggestion but what if the laptop is in new condition its just in new like condition works perfectly fine. Then ? As u said that every part is documented by the 'real' vendors.so my laptop is not documented, so how that may cause me in trouble ?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, an IP is most often linked to your location, not your device. If that laptop was used in Brazil before for criminal activities at IP X, it won't take that IP back to you. You will get your own IP from your own ISP.

Secondly, laptops are not registered in any way except those used by some companies.

Thirdly, buying stolen property is fencing, which is illegal in nearly every civilized country. If you have reason to suspect the laptop has been stolen from someone else, DO NOT BUY IT.

Fourthly, yes, you can be traced online, and not just by the police, but also by your ISP, advertising companies and the wedsites that you visit. There is no feasible way to avoid this apart from using TOR, which is a lot slower and makes you suspect, since TOR is very often used by criminals.

Fifthly, This entire question sounds very shady. You don't know where  the laptop comes from, you suspect it's stolen, you imply that the police has a reason to track this laptop and you keep saying that the device is not registered as if that is even possible. I strongly recommend you to not proceed with this purchase and acquire a laptop through a more official channel, like legitimate dealer.

Comment: If I could give this answer 10 votes I would.

Comment: But how anyone can know that the laptop is a stolen one ? If the ip address will be changed as changing the location ? Is there any way to know that the laptop being used is a stolen one ?

Comment: @shiv I read your other comments as well. What you have here is an unused laptop that's stolen before it reaches the store. It hasn't even had an IP yet. However, they can trace the serial numbers on certain parts if they inspect your laptop. This can only happen if your store reported the laptop stolen and can know what serial number has been stolen. I would just not buy this laptop and buy directly from the store. It might cost slightly more, but you really don't want to be caught fencing stolen goods.

Comment: @Nate thanks for ur suggestion, I have one more question, if I use TOR then also I can be traced ? If they have reported to the store about the missing laptop ?

Comment: @shiv They likely won't be able to see if your laptop has been stolen even if you just use a normal browser. What is possible is that some of the preinstalled software allows them to trace your laptop regardless of what mitigation steps you take short of either formatting or never connecting to the internet.